# Is it possible to add a column to Nautlius Preferences dialog ? Specifically, one that indicates the cardinal number of that file in the folder

Tags: nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.   My question is basically this.  In the Nautilus preferences, is it possible to add a column that shows the  ascending cardinal number that corresponds to a file in a given folder ?    Refer to the image.

[image]

We can see in the image that there is a "List Columns" tab. Is it possible to add a "Number" column to the list under this tab ?  The function I am looking for is one that enumerates  or numbers the files automatically (in ascending order) when you display a folder's contents using Nautilus. This means automatically placing an ascending number to the left of each filename, but of course in a different column.   I know this can be done through command line in terminal with "nl" command, but there are some tasks that are more efficiently done using Nautilus to display folder contents. Especially if you are selecting and  dragging files from one place to another and trying to keep track of which one you interacted with last.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is *community* support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

Comment: FYI:   Even help on *moving you to a supported release* now involves re-install on sites like this, as 16.04 will only *release-upgrade* to 18.04 which is itself now EOSS too and thus off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature bundled with nautilus. Even the API makes this quite difficult, so I tried to put whatever I could together.

Since 16.04 is EOL, I will give some instructions that have only been tested on 23.10. The names may need adjusting.

First, install support for Python extensions in nautilus: `sudo apt install python3-nautilus`.

Create a new file (and parent directories) at `~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/cardinal-number.py`, and paste the following into it:

```py
import os.path
from urllib.parse import unquote
from gi.repository import GObject, Nautilus
from typing import List


class ColumnExtension(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.ColumnProvider, Nautilus.InfoProvider):
    def get_columns(self) -> List[Nautilus.Column]:
        column = Nautilus.Column(
            name="NautilusPython::cardinal",
            attribute="cardinal",
            label="Cardinal number",
            description="Get the cardinal number",
        )

        return [
            column,
        ]

    def update_file_info(self, file: Nautilus.FileInfo) -> None:
        filename = unquote(file.get_uri()[7:])
        dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)
        basename = os.path.basename(filename)

        alphabetic_sort_key = lambda x: x # Do nothing and return the file name
        chronological_sort_key = lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirname, x))
        # Change the following line to whichever order you want
        sort_key = alphabetic_sort_key

        # This is extremely inefficient because
        # it lists and sorts the directory for every file
        # But we will have to make do with it because "file: Nautilus:FileInfo"
        # does not appear to include the index, or point to any data structure
        # where information about the directory is stored
        directory_listing = sorted(os.listdir(dirname), key=sort_key)

        offset = 0 # Replace 0 with 1 if you want to start counting from 1
        file.add_string_attribute("cardinal", str(offset + directory_listing.index(basename)))
```

Run `killall nautilus` before reopening nautilus to ensure the new extension is loaded.

Then you can right click the rightmost part of the column headers:

[image: visible columns right click menu]

Click "Visible Columns", then scroll down and enable my new "Cardinal number" column:

[image: visible columns window]

The final result should look like this:

[image: demo of the cardinal number column on /]

Comment: thanks for the response.   this code looks promising.   before i try this though, may i ask what part of this code increments or increases the counting of the files in a given folder ?

Comment: This code doesn't really "increment" anything, due to how nautilus is architected. 1. The "sorted(...)" function takes the randomly-ordered list of files in the directory, and orders them alphabetically. Then I call `directory_listing.index(basename)` to get the count. Replace `sorted` with something else if you want to order by something else. 2. If you want to count from 1 instead of 0, then replace `str(` with `str(1+`

Comment: hhmmm, i see. just so i understand better, using my image above as an example.  all those screenshot files are displayed by Nautilus already in alphabetic order, or (in this case)  chronologically according to timestamp.   Is this not what Nautilus does anyway ?   Help me understand how your code will have Nautilus display other files that do not have automatic timestamps while numbering them in ascending order AND  displaying those numbers  next to the filenames.

Comment: In `update_file_info`, nautilus doesn't give us access to the alphabetic order or the numbering. Therefore, we need to recalculate it there to get the number.

Comment: `file.add_string_attribute("cardinal",` gives Nautilus tells Nautilus what number to put on the current line. Then Nautilus's original code in its "Visible columns" window enables displaying the newly added attribute

Comment: @keikaku I edited my code to support chronological order. Change `sort_key = alphabetic_sort_key` to `sort_key = chronological_sort_key` to enable it

Comment: cool, i get it.  i will definitely try this and then give you an update.  also, i noticed that you edited the images you posted.  two of them were not there before. that helped because i just saw the "cardinal number"  column in the third image.   i was expecting this column to be on the left, before the "name" column so i did not even notice if it was there earlier.  100 thanks for your effort and explanations. and i will update you soon.  one last question for the day:  is there a book i can study that explains the same things that  you explained to me today ?

Comment: You can just drag the "Cardinal number" column to the left. You're welcome. I added the images to clarify where to enable things, but things may be in a different place on 16.04, so I highly recommend upgrading to a supported version of Ubuntu. I copied the column provider extension template from https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/nautilus-python/class-nautilus-python-column-provider.html . Then the rest of the code I Googled on StackOverflow about how to do various things. If you're specifically looking for a book, I would recommend just any generic book on Python programming

Comment: hi daniel,  i  just  made the same edits and tried the code.  so far,  i  am not getting the result you got.  i also copied the new file to the  .config/nautilus  folder.  this  does not work  either.  any  suggestions ?  thanks

Comment: Please make sure you did `sudo apt install python3-nautilus` , and that the code appears when you do `~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/cardinal-number.py` . Also, please update to at least 20.04 LTS (or even better 22.04 LTS), as 16.04 is off-topic EOL and I don't have a machine to test it and the python3-nautilus package may have changed in the meantime